# Python Webdrive

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two file main.py and test.py
And i need to **Scrape** data from soccerway but first i need to input Date example 2011/2012 or range from 2011/2019
How can i solve

```
main.py
date = input ("Insert Date: ")

test.py


from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from scraper import scrape_match
from write_to_spread import write_spread
from season import get_urls_season
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.fullscreen_window()
driver.get("https://us.soccerway.com" + url_path)
click_privacy_policy(driver)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='season_id']/option[text('how can input date')]").click()
```

I need to type the date for example 2018/2019 and to get in this date or to input 2010-2019 and to get in every page

Comment: can you share the full url??

Comment: https://us.soccerway.com/national/azerbaijan/premyer-liqa/20192020/regular-season/r53041/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the input and `split` the input to get the start and end year and do string manipulation and it will click as you are looking after.

```
inptdate='2010-2019'
startdate=inptdate.split('-')[0]
enddate=inptdate.split('-')[1]

while int(startdate)<int(enddate):

 textstring=str(startdate) + "/" + str(int(startdate)+1)
 print(textstring)
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='season_id']/option[text()='" + textstring +"']").click()
 startdate=int(startdate)+1
```

Comment: `inptdate='2010-2012'
    startdate=inptdate.split('-')[0]
    enddate=inptdate.split('-')[1]
    while int(startdate)<int(enddate):
       textstring=str(startdate) + "/" + str(int(startdate)+1)
       print(textstring)
       driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='season_id']/option[text()='" + textstring +"']").click()
       url_list = cycle_through_game_weeks(driver)
       startdate=int(startdate)+1
       url_list.reverse()
    

    driver.quit()`

Comment: When i insert link and start scraping in 2010-2011 2011-2012 and get in all links in this page at this moment all is ok but when extract is the problem because extract only the last year can you help why?

Comment: Can you please post a new question with code what you are trying and your expected output??

Comment: Why in the script when insert from x date to y date saved only the last date